# event not work after generating new elements by using "on" in jquery

Tags: jquery, bind, document

I want to change an select element into an textfield element and backwards:

```
$(document).on('change','.sel1', function() {
    if($('select option:selected').val() == 4) {
        var sCol = $(this).attr('name').substr(0,5);
        var nCol = $(this).attr('name').substr(5,2);
        $('#tabSel'+nCol).html('<input type=\"text\" name=\"'+sCol+nCol+'s\" maxlength=\"255\">&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class=\"del del2\" id=\"'+sCol+nCol+'s\"><b>X</b></span>');
        $('input[name='+sCol+nCol+'s]').focus();
    }
});
```

With an other event I generate new select-elements and all the have the class `.sel`.
But it only works for the just existing elements, not for the new generated.

```
$('sel1').bind('change', function() {
if($('select option:selected').val() == 4) {
    var sCol = $(this).attr('name').substr(0,5);
    var nCol = $(this).attr('name').substr(5,2);
    $('#tabSel'+nCol).html('<input type=\"text\" name=\"'+sCol+nCol+'s\" maxlength=\"255\">&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class=\"del del2\" id=\"'+sCol+nCol+'s\"><b>X</b></span>');
    $('input[name='+sCol+nCol+'s]').focus();
}
});
```

also not works.

Comment: The class `.sel` or the class `.sel1`, which is the one you're targeting ?

Comment: Hi Adeneo,

sure, the class is sel1.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind that change event after you generate the new select list. New elements created after an event binding don't automatically get registered even though the class or id matches the original binding.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That means: bind() after the append event (the event I generate the new.)?

Comment: Actually looking at your code again, the on() event delegate should work with dynamically created elements. Make sure the new elements you're making are created with the right class, it should be .sel1 based on your example and not .sel.

Comment: Hello bitwiser,

the bind or the on Funktion seems ok. Maybe that part is not suitable:
    if($('select option:selected').val() == 4) {

Comment: Hello bitwiser,

the bind or the on Funktion seems ok. Maybe that part is not suitable, where I am asking for the value:

    if($('select option:selected').val() == 4) {

because I get the value of the other select-ones.
How I get the value of this element?

Comment: Ah, with that selector you're grabbing all of the select lists. You want something like this $(this).find('option:selected').val() that will get the value of the select list that fired the event.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I get the right value. But it works only one time at the first select-one  in the same way as the generated new ones. I get also no output or alert at this place of script the second time, neither with on() nor with bind ().